# Can I send message directly from Safari Web Extension’s background page to Native App?

Tags: macos, safari, web-extension

I am developing a safari web extension. I need send data from Web Extension’s background page to native app. Native app gets this message and signs it with USB key to generate a signature value. Then Native app sends the signature value back to background page.
[Messaging a Web Extension’s Native App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/messaging_a_web_extension_s_native_app?language=objc)

First, I create a port in background.js

```
let port = browser.runtime.connectNative("application.id");
```

Add a listener to that port to receive message from Native App，as follow:

```
port.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    console.log("Received native port message:");
    console.log(message);
});
```

In my native app, I can send message to background page with following codes:

```
SFSafariApplication.dispatchMessage(withName: "Hello from App", 
     toExtensionWithIdentifier: extensionBundleIdentifier,
     userInfo: ["AdditionalInformation": "Goes Here"], 
     completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in
          os_log(.default, "Dispatching message to the extension finished")
 })
```

But how can I send message from background page to Native App?
In “Messaging a Web Extension’s Native App” demo, messages are send by following code:

```
port.postMessage("Hello from JavaScript Port");
```

But there are no codes to show how to receive this message in native app.

In native app, How can I receive messages sent by “postMessage” from background page? If you can provide a demo with object-C, I will be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the following answer to your question in the WWDC'20 session [`Meet Safari Web Extensions`](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10665/)

> **App ⭤ extension**:
>
> Shared NSUserDefaults from an app group, or NSXPCConnection

See also [WWDC NOTES](https://www.wwdcnotes.com/notes/wwdc20/10665/)